# How to query and return an individual field from a nested embedded document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build a verb database where:

- each verb has many conjugations
- each conjugation has one tense name (present, imperfect, ...) and many forms
- each form has a personal pronoun (io, tu, ...) and the actual conjugated verb (conjugation)

I choose this structure because I want to do two types of queries:

1. Given a verb, a tense and a pronoun, return the associated conjugation
2. Given a verb, show all of its tenses, pronouns and conjugations

I'm struggling with the first one. This is what I have so far (but it doesn't work):

```
db.verbs.findOne({"verb": "comprare", "conjugations": {"$elemMatch": {"tense": "present", "forms.pronoun": "io"}}}, {"conjugations.forms.conjugation": 1})
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
db.verbs.insert([{
                  "verb": "comprare",
                  "conjugations": [
                    {
                      "tense": "present",
                      "forms": [{"pronoun": "io", "conjugation": "compro"},
                                {"pronoun": "tu", "conjugation": "compri"}],
                    },
                    {
                      "tense": "imperfect",
                      "forms": [{"pronoun": "io", "conjugation": "compravo"},
                                {"pronoun": "tu", "conjugation": "compravi"}]
                    }
                  ]
                 },
                 {
                  "verb": "bere",
                  "conjugations": [
                    {
                      "tense": "present",
                      "forms": [{"pronoun": "io", "conjugation": "bevo"},
                                {"pronoun": "tu", "conjugation": "bevi"}]
                    },
                    {
                      "tense": "imperfect",
                      "forms": [{"pronoun": "io", "conjugation": "bevevo"},
                                {"pronoun": "tu", "conjugation": "bevevi"}]
                    }
                  ]
                 }])
```

I'm willing to change the structure of the database to make it easier to query, so feel free to suggest a more natural way to do it.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework `$unwind` in the pipeline to create documents from nested arrays. You have two nested arrays, so you will unwind twice.

```
db.verbs.aggregate([
  // match documents with specific verb
  {$match: {verb: "comprare"}},
  // query each conjugation as a separate document
  {$unwind: "$conjugations"},
  // match conjugations with the provided tense
  {$match: {"conjugations.tense": "present"}},
  // query each form as a separate document
  {$unwind: "$conjugations.forms"},
  // match conjugation form with the provided pronoun
  {$match: {"conjugations.forms.pronoun": "io"}},
  // only select fields of interest
  {$project: {"conjugations": 1, _id: 0}}
]);
```

You can change the projection to get specific fields and even rename the fields and use an expression:

```
{"conjugations.forms.pronoun": 1}
-> {conjugations: {forms: {pronoun: "io"}}}
{"conjugation": "$conjugations.forms.conjugation"}
-> {conjugation: "compro"}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I want. How do I get it to return just the conjugation (`"compro"`)?

Comment: @nachocab updated the answer with more details for that